# Multiple select in sql

Tags: sql

I'm doing a database about attractions in a certain state, and I have these tables:

The first table is for the cities in a state

[image: cities table]

The other table is for wineries in those cities

[image: wineries table]

I'm having trouble printing the wineries and cities name together, any suggestions?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use join keyword to join two tables, for example:

```
select w.winery_Name, c.city_Name from Wineries w
inner join Cities c on w.city_ID = c.cities_ID;
```

[image]

Comment: Glad to help you, feel free to accept my answer :) thanks

Comment: Could please explain why you used w and c here "w.winery_Name, c.city_Name"

Comment: To get object reference. So 'w' is Wineries instance with winery_Name field inside.